# Could not meta description/keywords/author be in AMP page?

Tags: amp-html

I did not found the AMP example with `<meta>` of **description**, **keywords** and **author** types, but may I add them to AMP page?

Comment: yes. but it's better to encode conventional `<meta>` data in JSON-LD using schema.org. That is the preferred data source used by robots.

Comment: You can add these tags to the page. As far as I know, the meta keywords tag is not currently used, is not needed.